# How to zoom graph, created with CGContextRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgcontextref, cgcontextdrawpath

I am drawing a line graph by using **CGContextRef**. Can I zoom in zoom out this graph to show lines clearly.

I am using this code.

```
CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextBeginPath(context);

CGMutablePathRef path=CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, lastPointX, lastPointY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, newPointX, newPointY);

CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineColor);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGPathRelease(path);

if (isFilling) {
    CGMutablePathRef path=CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, newPointX, newPointY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, newPointX, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, lastPointX, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, lastPointX, lastPointY);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, fillingColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

Note:- I don't want to zoom view. I want to redraw lines to show clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw this graph on **UIScrollView** or you can add view on  **UIScrollView** then you can able to zoom in and out that graph.
To do this you should implement following methods of **UIScrollView**:

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
}
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
}
```

For reference you can follow this nice tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

which will tell you to implement following methods:

```
- (void)centerContentsOfScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
}
- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
}
- (void)scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
}
```

Comment: I don't want to zoom view. I want to redraw lines to show clearly.